# Not able to mock the getTimestamp method on mocked Row

Tags: scala, cassandra, mockito

I am writing an application that interacts with Cassandra using Scala. While performing unit testing, I am using mockito wherein I am mocking the resultSet and row

```
  val mockedResultSet = mock[ResultSet]
  val mockedRow = mock[Row]
```

Now while mocking the methods of the mockedRow, such as

```
  doReturn("mocked").when(mockedRow).getString("ColumnName")
```

works fine. However, I am not able to mock the getTimestamp method of the mockedRow. I have tried 2 approaches but was not successful.

First approach

```
  val testDate = "2018-08-23 15:51:12+0530"
  val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
  val date: Date = formatter.parse(testDate)
  doReturn(date).when(mockedRow).getTimestamp("ColumnName")
```

and second approach

```
when(mockedRow.getTimestamp("column")).thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2018-08-23 15:51:12+0530"))
```

Both of them return null i.e it does not return the mocked value of the getTimestamp method. I am using cassandra driver core 3.0 dependency in my project.
Any help would br highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Mocking objects you don't own is usually considered a bad practice, that said, what you can do to try to see what's going on is to verify the interactions with the mock, i.e.

```
verify(mockedRow).getTimestamp("column")
```

Given you are getting null out of the mock, that statement should fail, but the failure will show all the actual calls received by the mock (and it's parameters), which should help you to debug.

A way to minimize this kind of problems is to use a [mockito session](http://blog.mockito.org/2017/01/clean-tests-produce-clean-code-strict.html), in standard mockito they can only be used through a JUnit runner, but with [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#orgmockitomockitoscalasession) you can use them manually like this

```
MockitoScalaSession().run {
   val mockedRow = mock[Row]
   when(mockedRow.getTimestamp("column")).thenReturn(Timestamp.valueOf("2018-08-23 15:51:12+0530"))
   //Execute your test
}
```

That code will check that the mock is not being called with anything that hasn't been stubbed for, it will also tell you if you had provided stubs that weren't actually used and a few more things.

If you like that behaviour (and you are using ScalaTest) you can apply it automatically to every test by using [MockitoFixture](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#mockitofixture)

I'm a developer of mockito-scala btw